# MVC Routing Issue, I'm stumped

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on an app and when I go to debug the application starts at: localhost:54591/Views/Home/Index.aspx and gives me a resource not found 404 error.

I get this same issue when I type in the url:
localhost:54591/Views/Home/Index.aspx

But for some reason when I type in the url:
localhost:54591/Views/Home/

It works but now my header menu is not formatted correctly.

So what gives? For the life of me I cannot figure out what is wrong. If I can just figure out how to reroute at startup to localhost:54591/Views/Home/ I could figure out why the menu is not working but I do have a hunch that these problems are related.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
       // routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would advise you read some ASP.NET MVC tutorials in general as it doesn't seem like you have grasped the context of how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not caused by routing (except 404 on non-existent page). By default VS will start web sites on page you are currently working on. So if you worked on Index.aspx at the moment of clicking F5 it will try to open that view.

To change the behavior - change start page in project's settings: Project properties -> Web -> change to "specific page".

Comment: Thanks, this worked to fix the startup issue. So do you think my menu not formatting correctly is related?

Comment: @BWoods, since it is broken for correct route -  I think unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

localhost:54591/Views/Home/Index.aspx shouldn't work as you should be using the controller to load the views. /Home/ for example

Comment: Well how can I load the /Home/ at startup instead of Views/Home/Index

Comment: Do you mean within Visual Studio start-up page? If so, simple right click the project and under the "Web" page set a specific page or start url to be /home/

Comment: Alex answered the question below that got me past the resource not found issue.

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behaviour.
On an MVC app you shouldnt access your views directly, instead, your contorllers.

Regarding the format issue, you would have to provide more details, but you App is working fine